# smook etl tool for b2b xml edi

Tags: xml, edi

I am looking at mapping edi,xml csv and other formats data to java objects and relational formats.

I have searched and found http://www.smooks.org is is the right tool for my job or should i rely on apache camel.

for some use cases i want the business analyst to do the mapping using a GUI.

Answer (score 3):

I think Smooks might be a good choice for you.

It is very convenient to map XML, CSV and EDL files to Java beans using Smooks, have a look at some of these examples:

http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.3:xml-to-java
http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=V1.3:edi-to-java
http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Smooks_v1.3_Examples

These Java beans (they could be simple HashMaps and ArrayLists) can also be used to construct other data from text produced by the Freemarker templating language.

If you have very large files, Smooks is good because it can use a SAX parsing model. It is also a quite light and easy framework to learn.

It has a graphical IDE using Eclipse, but I would probably recommend that you try it out to see whether it could be useful for your business analysts:
http://www.smooks.org/mediawiki/index.php?title=Eclipse_IDE